# Hide dynamic google map markers with checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am attempting to create a filter for some dynamic markers on a Google map. The user selects which markers they would like to filter with various check box selections relating to each marker category.

I would like some advice on my current code as I am hoping that I am quite close. I am aware that there are a number of similar questions on here although they all seem to follow an xml google map tutorial which I am not following and have taken the JSON / $.each route rather than generating XML and for loops to set the markers position.

From reading the related questions, I have tried to create an array that groups the markers by their category and then based on which check boxes are selected should hide or unhide these markers.

Currently when I run the code the checkboxes are frozen on check and do not uncheck. When I remove the onClick from the html the issue is resolved, although this then doesn't call the funtion.

I get a javascript error that the toggleGroup function is not defined. I don't understand why as it is supposed to be defined by the checkbox id.

**JS**

```
var customIcons = [];
    customIcons["1"] = 'img/32x32/border_edits/Automotive.jpg';
    customIcons["2"] = 'img/32x32/border_edits/BarPub.jpg';
    customIcons["3"] = 'img/32x32/border_edits/Cinema.jpg';

var markerGroups = { 
    "1": [],
    "2": [],
    "3": []
};

$(document).on("pageshow","#map-page",function(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
    } else {
        error('Geo Location is not supported');
    }

    function success(position) {
        var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        var options = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: coords,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            disableDefaultUI:true,
            zoomControl:true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: coords,
            icon: 'img/gps_marker.jpg',
            map: map,
        });


        $.post( "getrow.php?getjson", function( data ) {    
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function(index, value){

                var id = value.site_id;
                var type = value.prime_category;
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon);
                var name = value.site_name;
                var address = value.site_address;
                var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
                var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, type, id);
            });
        });

        function createMarker(point, name, address, type, id) {
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  position: point,
                  icon: customIcons[type],
                  id: id
              });      
              markerGroups[type].push(marker);
              var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                  infoWindow.setContent(html);
                  infoWindow.open(map, marker);

              });
              return marker;
        }

        function toggleGroup(type){
            if($('#'+type).is(':checked')){
                for(var i=0;i<markerGroups[type].length;i++){
                    markerGroups[type][i].setVisible(true);
                }
            }
            else{
                for(var i=0;i<markerGroups[type].length;i++){
                    markerGroups[type][i].setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }                   
    }
});
```

**HTML**

I have the checkboxes in a jquery mobile dialog page that is linked in the header of the map page

```
<div data-role="page" id="map-page">
    <div data-role="header" id="appheader" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>
        <a href="#preferences" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-rel="dialog" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true"></a> 
        </h1>
    </div>  
    <div id="appcontent">
        <div id="map">
        </div>      
    </div> 
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="preferences">
    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Filter</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <label for="1">Automotive</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="1" onClick="toggleGroup(this.id)" checked>
                <label for="3">Cinema</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="3" onClick="toggleGroup(this.id)" checked>
                <label for="5">Dining Out</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="5" onClick="toggleGroup(this.id)" checked>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#appcontent{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#map{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

#appheader{
    position: absolute;    
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;    
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #00a2e8;
}
```

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where did you define the methods isHidden, show and hide ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including any required JSON/CSS required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors? You probably should be.

Comment: I have added the css and the rest of my JS code. Apologies, I have been working on this quite some time and my code kind of blurs together I've been staring at it so long. @Clayton Leis - I get "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" JS error.

Comment: I think you can only call push on arrays and not objects. markerGroups being an object.

Comment: Also, I wonder if toggleGroup is ever called the way you have it. I don't normally use 'onclick' and the like, but I wouldn't think toggleGroup would be in scope for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this problem. Rather than call the function from the onClick of each checkbox in html. I used $(":checkbox").change to call the function and use this.id to define the marker's type. Thanks to @Clayton Leis for that suggestion.

**JS**

```
function createMarker(point, name, address, type, id) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: customIcons[type],
        id: id
    });      
    markerGroups[type].push(marker);
    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    return marker;
}

$(":checkbox").change(function toggleGroup(){
    var type = this.id; 
    if($('#'+type).is(':checked')){
        for(var i=0;i<markerGroups[type].length;i++){
            markerGroups[type][i].setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    else{
        for(var i=0;i<markerGroups[type].length;i++){
            markerGroups[type][i].setVisible(false);
        }
    }       
});
```

One remaining problem I have is that the checkboxes are on a dialog page using jquery mobile in the html. When the page is closed it refreshes the html which resets the checkboxes. It seems like this is a well known problem with dialog pages in jquery mobile but when I put the checkbox code in the map page the code above works perfectly. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar checkbox months ago. I think your code is right

You just need something like this in you HTML (your code seems to be good):

```
<input id="1" type="checkbox" onchange="filterMarkers(this.id)"/>
```

And the javascript. I used setVisible(bool), this could be your problem:

```
function filterMarkers(type){
    if($('#'+type).is(':checked')){
        for(var i=0;i<mapMarkers[type].lenght;i++){
            mapMarkers[type][i].setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    else{
        for(var i=0;i<mapMarkers[type].lenght;i++){
            mapMarkers[type][i].setVisible(false);
        }
    }
```

---

I assume that you obtain correctly the values in your AJAX call. By the console error, you must probably have some problem there.

---

EDIT

Have you tried to see which are the values inside this loop?

```
var data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data);
$.each(data, function(index, value){
    // Do a console.log(value)
    var id = value.site_id;
    var type = value.prime_category;
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon);
    var name = value.site_name;
    var address = value.site_address;
    var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
    var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, type, id);
});
```

You're declaring a new **var** called 'data', same as the variable that comes from the function. It could be a problem.

Comment: thanks for the code, it's nice to know that I'm on the right tracks. I still get the javascript error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

Comment: Apologies, I had just seen your edit. Do you think that it could be conflicting with the push property? With my current code I don't have any problems with extracting the markers from the database etc. I will have a tinker with what you have suggested

Comment: The error you say suggest me that the problem is in this line: **markerGroups[type].push(marker);** Have you checked if 'type' corresponds to 1, 2 or 3 there?

Comment: I have updated my code with your suggested function. Somehow the push error has gone but I now get an error that the function is not defined. This is even more confusing to me as I thought that it was being defined by the id of the checkbox.

Comment: And also, realize that you're **declaring** the functions inside the **$(document).on()** function, so they're not visible for the HTML